# Apache2.4 will load 5.7MB Allow from IP list, but not 5.7MB Require from IP list

Tags: apache-2.4

Strange problem with loading Country Blocklists into an apache2 Virtual Host.
Both files are 5.7MB but the first one loads quickly with no issues.   I have not been able to successfully load the other.   The error I keep getting is a Timeout.   I've tried increasing the appropriate php variables AND the Apache Timeout value to no avail.  No matter what, the second file times out after almost exactly 90 seconds.

This loads just fine....

```
allow from 3.0.0.0/9
allow from 3.128.0.0/10
allow from 3.192.0.0/10
allow from 4.0.0.0/8
allow from 5.8.44.0/25
allow from 5.8.44.128/25
allow from 5.8.63.0/24
allow from 5.10.64.8/29
allow from 5.10.64.160/29
allow from 5.10.64.176/28
allow from 5.10.64.224/29
allow from 5.10.64.232/29
allow from 5.10.64.240/29
allow from 5.10.65.96/28
allow from 5.10.65.140/31
```

But not this.....

```
 <RequireAny>
 Require ip 216.200.243.208/28
 Require ip 216.200.243.224/27
 Require ip 216.200.244.0/23
 Require ip 216.200.246.0/24
 Require ip 216.200.247.0/28
 Require ip 216.200.247.16/29
 Require ip 216.200.247.24/31
 Require ip 216.200.247.27/32
 Require ip 216.200.247.28/30
 Require ip 216.200.247.32/30
 Require ip 216.200.247.36/32
 Require ip 216.200.247.38/31
 Require ip 216.200.247.40/32
```

and so forth....

What could cause this?

Comment: I hope you’re setting those access controls in your main httpd.conf and not from a .htaccess file...

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to put them in the server configuration file which is apache2.conf.    Any idea why one file would load but not the other?